# I just installed xampp on ubuntu 14.04, mysql is not starting in control panel

Tags: mysql, xampp

I just installed xampp on ubuntu.

When I am starting xampp using `sudo /opt/lampp/xampp start`, I am getting:

```
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
```

But in xampp control panel, mysql can not be executed.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Any reason for not choosing our own native lamp stack? That one works out of the box :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all run these two commands

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

If that doesn't solve your problem than run following command in terminal one at a time

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp
sudo chown -hR nobody /opt/lampp
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp
```

Than start server and you will be good to go